# Cosmos DB differentiation strategy when storing multiple document types in a single container

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I'm building a .Net C# project, using the CosmosDb SDK.

I have configured my Cosmos DB with a container called "UserData", with `\UserId` as a partition key.

The idea being that the container will store all data associated with a `User` entity (C# class).  The `User` entity has a `UserId` property which has the same value as the `Id` property.  In my scenario, a user can complete any number of quizzes (there is a separate `Quiz` entity (C# class) with a `UserId` property which represents completed quizzes.  There can also be transactions associated with a user.  `Transaction` is also a separate entity (C# class) with a `UserId` property.

I'm thinking to map all these entities to the single container called "UserData" (research has lead me to believe that documents that can be grouped by a meaningful partitionkey should be in the same container).  The `\UserId` partition key means that all data associated with a user will be in a single partition.  So far so good.

It so happens that the `Quiz` class and the `User` class happen to contain a property called `Email`, which leads to the problem I am experiencing below.

I have a problem regarding the `signin` process of my app.  When a user signs in (with their email address) I need to query the database for a `User` with that email address, like so:

```
var parameterizedQuery = new QueryDefinition(
    query: "SELECT * FROM Users p WHERE p.Email = @email"
)
    .WithParameter("@email", "<email address here>");

using FeedIterator<User> filteredFeed = container.GetItemQueryIterator<User>(
    queryDefinition: parameterizedQuery
);

while (filteredFeed.HasMoreResults)
{
    FeedResponse<User> response = await filteredFeed.ReadNextAsync();

    foreach (User item in response)
    {
        //deserialization error here because the query matched a Quiz document
    }
}
```

The query is matching a `Quiz` document, but my code is trying to deserialize the match into a `User` class.  And an exception is thrown.

Is there any guidance as to how to handle this kind of problem when storing different document types in a single container?  I've noticed that when using Cosmos DB with EF, they append a `Discriminator` property to the stored document.  Is this the right approach though?  How do other implementation solve this problem?

Comment: There is no exact answer to this, but typically something like an `entitytype` property is added to mixed-type documents, so you can filter on a particular type within your query (e.g. within your `WHERE` clause of a `SELECT`).

Comment: Yeah I've gone with a similar approach than EF...I've added a `Discriminator` property to each of my Entity classes, with a hard-coded string value for each class.